# How to expand all folders (not folded code blocks) in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Please note that I am not referring to folded code blocks, but to the folders in the Project View.

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> collapses all folders (Project View).

There's also an icon to collapse all folders in the Project View. However, I don't see an icon or a command in the keymap that expand all folders in the Project View.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is it possible? If so, how?

**Yes and No.**

---

If you want one button/action that would **expand all tree nodes till the very end (recursively)** (opposite to collapse all) -- **then answer is "No"**.

Why?

> [[1]](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70215#comment=27-247222) "Expand all" in Project view is meaningless for any reasonable-sized project, for performance and other reasons.
>
> [[2]](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90984#comment=27-376542) At least in debugger, most of the trees can be expanded infinitely and this is not always obvious when you're about to expand one. Do you realize that?

The 2nd one can also apply to Project View because of cyclic symbolic links.

Related tickets:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96225
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52772
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-90984
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106264

---

**But "Yes" -- you can expand next level in all sub folders simultaneously** (one level at a time). So using it few times in a row will most likely expand whole tree (depends on how deep the tree is).

For that just use <kbd>NumPad *</kbd> on desired main node (e.g. project root).

**P.S.** You can re-assign shortcut to whatever else you desire -- corresponding action is called `Fully Expand Tree Node`.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. I know it's not the best, but at times I need to expand them all. My projects are not that big.

Comment: why isn't this feature in the context menu where everyone would expect it to be?

Comment: There should really be a button to expand all (even just the next level is better than nothing). Especially in the 2016.1 edition where the project window has a "changed files" scope you can use to show only the changed files (of which you won't have that many and may reasonably expect to expand all). The lack of this feature makes the "changed files" project view highly inconvenient.

Comment: Point [1] about being meaningless is wrong. If I apply a filter to only see all files with changes, for example, expand all has all the meaning in the world.

Comment: @Kyopaxa [1] reason might indeed be wrong now .. as that view/scope (Changed files) has been added to the Project View panel only recently (*2016.1 I believe*). At the time of the initial comment (2011) it was perfectly valid point...