# PhpStorm - can I expand all folders?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have the project directory set to: show changed files.

I am wondering if I can somehow expand all the folders so I can see all the files that were changed.

[image]

SOLUTION FOR ME:

the action/command: Fully Expand Tree Node

Comment: Please show a screenshot (I'm not sure that I'm familiar with that screen/dialog). It might have dedicated "Expand all" button. if not -- try generic method as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413659/783119

Comment: So there is a collapse all button but no expand all.  The link you provided did the trick though.  @LazyOne thank you much